# Atomic function inside While

Tags: java, while-loop, atomicinteger

could someone explain me about this code please?

```
public class Counter {
        private AtomicInteger value = new AtomicInteger();

        public int incrementLongVersion(){//THIS PART2!!!
                int oldValue = value.get();
                while (!value.compareAndSet(oldValue, oldValue+1)){
                         oldValue = value.get();
                }
                return oldValue+1;
        }

}
```

i mean why can't i just change this code

```
!value.compareAndSet(oldValue, oldValue+1)
```

to

```
false
```

? I know there will be compile error statement never reached but why

```
!value.compareAndSet(oldValue, oldValue+1)
```

is not getting error? isn't it always false too right?

Or why can't I just clear that while loop and just return "oldValue+1"?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: If you just return, how do you remember the old value so you can keep incrementing?

Comment: But yes `AtomicInteger` has its own increment methods you can use.

Comment: No, it's _not_ always false.

Answer (score 1):

If `incrementLongVersion` is called from multiple threads, `value.compareAndSet(oldValue, oldValue+1)` may return `false`. The purpose of the `while` loop is to make sure that the function returns a value that's unique among all working threads.

A better way to implement this would be to simply use `incrementAndGet` from `AtomicInteger`.

```
public class Counter {
        private AtomicInteger value = new AtomicInteger();

        public int incrementLongVersion(){
                return value.incrementAndGet();
        }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is always `false` because **you know** what that function do, however the compiler does not analyze the body of given method call to check the return value will always be the same, false in this case.